# When is the address of a const reference function parameter unique?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, stack-memory, addressof, pass-by-const-reference

In my example code below, I'd like to know when two calls to `log_cref_address` will reliably print the same address.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

void log_cref_address(const int& t) {
    cout << addressof(t) << ' ';
}

template <int i>
void foo() {
    log_cref_address(i); // different if foo called from different threads
    thread([] { log_cref_address(i); }).join(); // same if already in thread
    thread(log_cref_address, i).join(); // same if already in thread
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    // first three calls print identical addresses
    cout << "foo<0>: "; foo<0>(); 
    cout << "foo<0>: "; foo<0>();
    cout << "foo<1>: "; foo<1>();
    cout << endl;
    // last two from thread yields different addresses from the first three
    cout << "lambda: "; thread([] { foo<0>(); }).join();
    cout << "bind(): "; thread(bind(foo<0>)).join();
    return 0;
}
```

On my machine, `main` prints

```
foo<0>: 0x7fff7cf5507c 0x7fa0585b5e1c 0x196fc28 
foo<0>: 0x7fff7cf5507c 0x7fa0585b5e1c 0x196fc28 
foo<1>: 0x7fff7cf5507c 0x7fa0585b5e1c 0x196fc28 

lambda: 0x7fa0585b5dcc 0x7fa057db4e1c 0x7fa0500008c8 
bind(): 0x7fa0585b5d1c 0x7fa057db4e1c 0x7fa0500008c8
```

From many outputs like this, I've observed that `main` behaves as follows:

1. The first three calls to `foo` print identical addresses.
2. The last two calls to `foo` (from threads) print addresses not printed by the first three calls.
3. In the last two calls to `foo`, `log_cref_address` prints the same address if and only if called from a sub-thread.

Which (if any) of these behaviors are guaranteed by the C++ standard, on any machine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of them. The standard doesn't guarantee the address of a temporary variable.

Comment: Especially it doesn't guarantee prolongation the lifetime  of temporary variables.